# Trouble with While

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

While code freezes debug.   Loops infinitely?  But I'm not sure how as I have a defined end condition which should be met.

The sheet I am working with is an inventory sheet.  I have another script that automatically catalogs shipments when they leave the warehouse on a separate tab, which then leaves empty rows of data.  I want to shift the data up to the first empty row.  The script will do this when ran multiple times, however, if all data is condensed when the script is ran, it will move the last data row to the first empty row, which is actually below the last data row at this point.

```
function shift() {
  //this sheet
  var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var thissheet = spr.getSheetByName('CURRENT MONTH');

  //define last row with data
  var lastRow = thissheet.getLastRow();
  var range = thissheet.getRange("A" + lastRow);
  if (range.getValue() !== "") {
    var lastDataRow = lastRow;
  } else {
    var lastDataRow = range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  }

  //define first empty row
  var column = thissheet.getRange('A11:A');
  var values = column.getValues();
  var ct = 0;
  while (values[ct] && values[ct][0] != "") {
    ct++;
  }
  console.log(ct + 1);
  var firstEmptyRow = (ct + 1) + 10 //+10 accounts for header

  //the range to copy to (first empty row)
  var emptyrange = thissheet.getRange(firstEmptyRow, 1, 1, 15);

  //the copy and clear code
  while (lastDataRow > firstEmptyRow) {
    thissheet.getRange(lastDataRow, 1, 1, 15).copyTo(emptyrange);
    thissheet.getRange(lastDataRow, 1, 1, 15).clearContent();
  }
}
```

My solution was to use While to shift data until the last data row number is less than the first empty row number, thus While (lastDataRow > firstEmptyRow) should run as long as there is data below an empty row.

Comment: The last `while` should be `if`, since you never change the variables inside the loop.

Comment: That...makes so much sense.  I'm such a noob.  Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I changed it to If but I still need it to loop.  Is there a way within If to loop it until that condition is no longer true?

Comment: You can use a `while` loop, but you need to change one of the variables inside the loop so that the condition changes.

Comment: Maybe you should be using a `for` loop instead? It's not clear what you're really trying to do there.

Comment: I'm still a bit unfamiliar with while and for loops.  My variables change as the rows shift up, but I understand that's not what it needs necessarily.  Basically, all I want is my data to shift up when a row is cleared.  So it reads the first available row and the last row with data and it puts that data into the first available row then clears the last row.  I want this to loop until the last row with data is less than the first empty row, i.e. all my data is shifted to the top most rows.

Comment: Calling `copyTo()` and `clearContent()` doesn't change either of those variables.

Comment: the variables should be the number of the row, for example, last row with data is row 16, first empty row is row 11.  When the statement runs and the condition is re-evaluated, the last row with data would be 11 and the first empty row would be 12, assuming no other data.  I apologize if I am not understanding something.  Thank you very much for your help Barmar.

Comment: `for (row = firstEmptyRow; row < lastDataRow; row++) { ... }`

Comment: Well, it the debug doesn't freeze and doesn't return any errors, but the function itself doesn't do anything.  My statements aren't triggering.  So I know I will need to do this a max of 50 times and I know the IF statement works the way I need it to.  I am going to try ```for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {...}```

Comment: Okay, it seems what is happening now is that my if statement works but if I try to do it more than once at a time it won't copyto and will only clearcontent, so I end up losing data.  ```if (lastDataRow > firstEmptyRow) 
  {thissheet.getRange(lastDataRow, 1, 1, 15).copyTo(emptyrange);
    thissheet.getRange(lastDataRow, 1, 1, 15).clearContent();}```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decrement `lastDataRow` each time through the loop

```
  while (lastDataRow > firstEmptyRow) {
    thissheet.getRange(lastDataRow, 1, 1, 15).copyTo(emptyrange);
    thissheet.getRange(lastDataRow, 1, 1, 15).clearContent();
    lastDataRow--;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the previous answer didn't help.  But I did figure this out.

```
while (true) {
thissheet.getRange(lastDataRow, 1, 1, 15).copyTo(emptyrange);
  thissheet.getRange(lastDataRow, 1, 1, 15).clearContent();
  Utilities.sleep(500);
  if (lastDataRow > firstEmptyRow) {
  break;}
  }
```

I used a manual break.  The sleep may not be necessary, but I wanted to delay it a bit to help it run more efficiently.  Again, I'm a noob, probably not necessary at all.  Anyway, just wanted to share my success.  Thanks again for all your help Barmar!

Comment: Also, I have great skills in overdoing things.  What I wanted to accomplish is very easily accomplished through a simple filter, which I had set up, but didn't even think about.  Smashing my face on the keyboard now.